# Bean 'x' of type [TYPE] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-aop

I have a `ResourceAspect` class:

```
//@Component
@Aspect
public class ResourceAspect {

    @Before("execution(public * *(..))")
    public void resourceAccessed() {
        System.out.println("Resource Accessed");
    }

}
```

Here is my `Application` class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication springApplication = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        springApplication.run(args);
    }
}
```

The dependencies that are being used inside the project are:

- spring-boot-starter
- spring-boot-configuration-processor
- spring-boot-starter-web
- spring-boot-starter-test
- spring-boot-devtools
- spring-boot-starter-security
- spring-boot-starter-aop

Whenever I add `@Component` to the `ResourceAspect`, the `resourceAccessed()` executes but it also throws an Exception `Bean 'x' of type [TYPE] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors`. Without `@Component`, `resourceAccessed()` does not execute. Any ideas?

Comment: `Bean 'x' of type [TYPE] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors` is this message displayed? or what is `x` and `TYPE`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that your pointcut `execution(* *(..))` (which basically says "intercept the world") affects too many components, even Spring-internal ones. Just limit it to the classes or packages you really want to apply your aspect to, e.g.

```
execution(* my.package.of.interest..*(..))
```

or

```
within(my.package.of.interest..*) && execution(* *(..))
```

You could also exclude the ones you don't need woven if that is easier to specify:

```
!within(my.problematic.ClassName) && execution(* *(..))
```

or

```
!within(my.problematic.package..*) && execution(* *(..))
```

BTW, of course your aspect needs to be a `@Component` when using Spring AOP (not AspectJ).